# Is there an any way to disable activity relaunch on theme change

Tags: android, android-10.0

I am working on a cross-platform 3d game, for android the engine and game logic are written in C ++ and interaction with the platform in Java. I ran into the following problem: when the system changes the theme (for example, android 10 turns on or off the dark theme when turning on / off the power saving mode), the game receives a RelaunchActivity message, due to which the onDestroy method is called. The problem is that due to the inability to normally unload native libraries from Java code, in the onDestroy method I have to call System.exit (0), which leads to the game termination. The question is, can we somehow tell the system that we do not need to change the theme, so that it does not send us a RelaunchActivity message?

Comment: Any solution found? @Vyacheslav Hrasiuk